# Video doesn't play in fragment

Tags: android

HI I'm making GymExercises App and every Exercise is written in different Fragment
so i want to  add Video to show how exercise to do,it compiles but doesn't show anything can someone help me ?
PS i don't need play,stop button and anything other just to show the video
Here is the code that i add

Example:

BenchFragment.java

```
 package com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises;


import android.media.session.MediaController;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.net.URL;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BenchFragment extends Fragment {


    public BenchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bench, container, false);
        VideoView view = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bench1;
        view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        view.start();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bench, container, false);
    }

}
```

fragment_bench.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.BenchFragment">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/group"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:fontFamily="Arial"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:padding="5dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/bencbody"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:fontFamily="Arial"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:fontFamily="Arial"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:padding="5dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:fontFamily="Arial"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/stepone"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:fontFamily="Arial"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/steptwo"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: every exercise in a different fragment? oh man. you should really look into some json structuring. one fragments is all you need. what format is the video? where are you getting the video from?

Comment: i need every exercise in different fragment because i use qr code scanner so when you scan example bench code it need to go to bench fragment but nmv i download video from yt i tried with few doesn't work.,,,

Comment: a qr code? no, no, no. deeplinks are way better. look that up. you downloaded them from youtube? why not use the youtube API and load the video that way?

Comment: i want to load the videos from local storage not online this is the reason....

Comment: have u tried this ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UriLJvlCenk

Comment: doesn't work...